# How is object of serialized class created dynamically without calling the constructor when de-serialization in java?

Tags: java, serialization, deserialization

How is object of serialized class created dynamically without calling the constructor when de-serialization in java?
What is the mechanism used by the JVM to create the object instance?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It depends on the JVM, but the Sun/Oracle/OpenJDK uses sun.misc.Unsafe.allocateInstance(Class)

```
   /** Allocate an instance but do not run any constructor.
       Initializes the class if it has not yet been. */
   public native Object allocateInstance(Class cls)
       throws InstantiationException;
```

http://www.docjar.com/html/api/sun/misc/Unsafe.java.html

This allows you to create new instances of just about anything e.g. enums, but not new instances of Class.